# Retrieving active session information from IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, session-state

I'm running several ASP.NET web sites with InProc session state and I would like to retrieve the number of active sessions per web site and hopefully any details around each session (eg client connection details). 
My end goal is to be able to see who is connected to the web site so that I can notify them when deploying an update.

Is there any way to do this in .NET without resorting to SQL session state? I looked at Microsoft.Web.Administration but couldn't find a way to do it. And the "Sessions Active" performance counter in perfmon just gives the total sessions for the whole server (as well as not giving any metadata about the sessions).

EDIT: In my tests with performance counters I tested with total Sessions Active when I should have tested with the instance of Sessions Active for my web site. This gets me a little closer but I'd still like to actually retrieve the session information for the web site if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Session is a concept, not an actuality.  You can use the asp.net global.asax pseudo events for session start/end to track this concept but it will still only be an approximation.  I think your best bet is to flip on your "maintenance in progress" flag and put something in the request pipeline that handles it for all incoming requests.

Not sure how/what you would do with this but I think you're going to be rolling some custom code here.